# Why my plain http request to poke my friend in fb failed?

Tags: facebook

While i am logged in, sending a plain http poke request to my friend but it fails every time. why? Status code is 302 Found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP status [302](http://httpstatus.es/302) means a redirect.

> The temporary URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the
>   response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the
>   response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the
>   new URI(s).

So it doesn't mean the request failed. You just have to look at another url (given in the Location header) to find the response.